# How to reset variable in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How do i reset the variable after `setstate` is called.

What i did i declared variable as empty string and i'm using socket. In `initstate` i'm listening the socket event and if any event is listened then i changed the declared variable to `"1"`. But once it is "1" i want this variable back to "" instead of going back to previous screen and coming back again. Below is the dart code

```
class _StatusTextState extends State<StatusText> {
  String check = "";
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    widget.socket.on('messageSeen', (data) {
      if (data['seen'] == true) {
        if (mounted) {
          setState(() {
            check = "1"; // Here it is changing to 1 after setstate variable should go back to ""
          });
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: We can set `check = "1"` after setState() function is called in mounted scope. But I think this isn't what you need. Please elaborate your scenario.

Comment: @BilalSaeed I also tried this but doesn't work. This check becomes empty string if i go back to previous screen and again come back.

Comment: @BilalSaeed i want this variable to "" once it execute setstate.

Comment: super.dispose();

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you would want to reset it right after setState but you could try use addPostFrameCallback() after setState(). This will reset check after the widget was built.

```
setState(() {
    check = "1";
});

WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => check = "");
```